How to modify the serviceAppointment to assign it to another serviceTerriory?
I am trying to update the service territory of a service appointment.
I was trying to use below API provided by salesforce scheduler.
[![][1]][1]
It gave me the following example:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
However when I test in postman, it gives me an internal error.
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
can any one know how to solve this?
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/WxIr299w.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/6HFaLqVB.png
[3]: https://i.sstatic.net/Wxuq9Dqw.png

I was wondering why the images didn't display, but I reasearched it and this person doesn't have enough repuation yet.
